# What is the actual mechanism behind the constructor initializer list?

Tags: c++, oop

There are cases where we must use an initializer list in order to initialize members, like when we have `const` data members. So, what makes an initializer list able to initialize members while the constructor itself can't?

Comment: "*while the constructor itself can't*" - I assume you mean the "constructor **body**". The initialization list is processed before the body is entered. All members have been fully  constructed before the body is entered. As such, only the initialization list is able to call member constructors. Anything assigned to members in the body is done through assignment, not initialization.

Comment: How does it work? Deep magic you're not likely to need to know until you start working on compilers. Is this deep magic what you are really interested in?

Comment: There are no mechanisms specified in the C++ standard. Only the laws of the language. This is one of them. `mem-initializer-list` initializes members, constructor body doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An initializer list always initializes all members. Full stop. Any members you fail to list have their default constructor called. If you reassign to them in the constructor body, then (in principle) you've just allocated and then immediately discarded one extra object.

In the particular case of `const`, a `const` variable cannot be *reassigned to*. It's never correct to set an initialized `const` variable equal to another value. It can *only* be initialized the first time, never reassigned.

```
struct Foo {
  const int x;
  int y;
  int z;

  Foo() : x(0), y(0) {
    // At this point, all three variables (even z) have been initialized.

    y = 0; // Okay, reassignment is fine but wasteful
    z = 0; // Same as above
    x = 0; // Error! Can't reassign to a const
  }

}
```

Comment: your answer was really helpful, thank you.

Comment: Some parts of your answer are wrong or at least imprecise. You can implement an `=` operator with the `const` modifier. Furthermore there's the possibility of constructor parameters being specified in the declaration of the member variable instead of the initializer list which would be a member that I'd consider to be "failed to be listed". Here's example code demonstrating my points: https://godbolt.org/z/75Y4e3q9r